# Using Zend rest controller with a zend rest client

Tags: php, zend-framework

Well this is my first trip to Zend and am faced with a task of setting a restful api. I used the zend rest controller whose code for example look like this:-

```
myzendrestcontroller-"localhost/alice/Theb2cController.php"
<?php

class Theb2cController extends Zend_Rest_Controller
{

   public function init() {
      $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
   }

   public function indexAction() {
       $this->getResponse()
            ->appendBody($xml);
   }

   public function getAction() {
      if ($this->getRequest ()->getParam ( "name" ) != NULL) {   
         $return =" wow";
      } else {
         $return= 'no parameters!';
      }

      echo $return
   }

   public function postAction() {
       $salutation=$this->getRequest()->getParam("salutation");  
   }

   public function putAction() {
   }

   public function deleteAction() {
      $this->getResponse()
            ->appendBody("From deleteAction() deleting the requested article");
   }
}
?>
```

The client looks like this:-

```
myzendclient-"localhost/alice1/theb2cclient.php"
require_once("Zend/Rest/Client.php");
$url="localhost/alice/Theb2cController.php"
$client1=new Zend_Rest_Client($url);
$client1->name('alice');
$response=$client1->get();
echo $response;
```

But I dont get any response, it is just a blank screen. Can someone please help

Comment: Do you use the whole MVC framework of Zend or only the Zend_Rest class as a stand alone object in your project?

Comment: @Adrian I am using only the zend rest classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you only get a blank screen, i.e. nothing at all then you should look at your error configuration. Make sure that all errors are shown in PHP with [display_errors](http://us.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) and [error_reporting](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

Second, there are problems all over. When you use the Zend_Rest_Controller as an independent object and not the whole Zend MVC Framework then you are most likely missing the router and all the `$this` references in your controller go nowhere really. Actually you should see errors when you call one of the actions but you are not as far as I see.

The Zend_Rest_Controller needs routing information and a view to render a document but when you call the `Theb2cController.php` file directly this all is clearly missing; including the error reporting! Find other ways to present a valid URL to your client without the controller information.

So, the following is not going to work because your `Theb2cController.php` is actually not doing and returning anything.

```
$url="localhost/alice/Theb2cController.php"
$client1=new Zend_Rest_Client($url);
```

Comment: when I run restful web service project, I am getting the error selection did not contain any resource that can run on a server. Kindly help me to resolve this. also please help me with a step by step guide to run one simple web service project